# How do I expand the full height of a lazy column in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a Lazy column like so

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(gridMultiple(i = 15) * data.size)
        .padding(vertical = gridMultiple(i = 2)),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(gridMultiple(i = 2)),
    userScrollEnabled = false
) {
    items(data.size) { index ->
        val item = data[index]

        ListItem(
            item,
            editButtonClick = { id -> onEditClick(id) }
        )
    }
}
```

and it is encapsulated in an interop composable XML element like so:

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
  android:id="@+id/informationList"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The catch is that the `informationList` is inside of a ScrollView (XML), and I want the lazy column list to be fully expanded within the scroll view. But I do not know the height that the elements need to be, so I am doing this math here:

`.height(gridMultiple(i = 15) * data.size)`

But it uses either too much space or not enough. So either elements get cut off, or they have a lot of empty space at the end. I want to use exactly as much space as the LazyColumn needs. If I set the height to be wrapping, I get an exception that the lazy column has an infinite possible height and must have a height specified. There must be a way to do this. I know that the max amount of elements that can ever be in the lazy column is limited to about 10.

Answer (score 0):

That will defeat the whole purpose of `LazyColumn`. The `lazy` part just won't work when you use it like that. You could just go with normal `Column` and it would make no difference at all in terms of performance. Especially with 10 items, with such number the `LazyColumn` is huge overkill. Bonus for your case - `Column` supports `wrapContentHeight()`.

TLDR - just use `Column` with `wrapContentHeight()` and it should be just fine

Comment: but `LazyColumn` is being used as `NestedScrollView` in compose. `NestedScrollView` has `android:Fillviewport` attribute

Comment: At the time of writing the Compose did not supported nested scrolling interop. But I still in this context (no more than 10 items) using simple column is more than enough

Comment: yes, found info about that we can use `Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())`)` now. Before that I thought that we still have to use `LazyColumn` to implement it somehow